# Visual Studio 2013 extension file doesn't open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

While trying to install the XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh extension, doubleclicking on the .vsix does nothing at all. Entirely nothing. No " stopped responding", no warning, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only doing a repair through the installer seemed to fix this.